# How to grant access to a cross-account role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I was given a cross account role A to access some resource in another account. I need to switch to this role A in order to access the resource in the other account. However when I switch role I lose access to resources in my current account. I want to attach the appropriate policy to A in my current account but A does not show up in IAM management console. What should I do in this case?

update: I have a Kinesis data stream in account A and I am setting up a Firehose in account B to store the data in an S3 in account B. A has granted me cross account access role to access the data stream in A. I tried to set this up in aws cli, but is getting: Cross-account pass role is not allowed exception.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately though AWS rakes in cash like autumn leaves, it can't be bothered to fix multiple issues with its web console, the most glaring of which is probably that you can't be logged into more than one account at a time per browser session.  you can use different browser sessions, or there's a number of browser extensions to work smarter around AWS.  "I want to attach the appropriate policy to A in my current account but A does not show up in IAM management console" Only the account that owns Role A can change its policies, and only with appropriate permissions.

Comment: You can only "assume" one role at a time. Please tell us more about your use-case (that is, what are you wanting to do?) because there are often ways to allow an IAM Role from another account to access resources in your own account -- such as using an Amazon S3 Bucket Policy. Are you simply wanting to copy S3 objects between the accounts?

Comment: "You can only "assume" one role at a time." in the *web console*.  If you're using API access you can use any number of roles simultaneously, the web console just doesn't support it.  I think OP is in the web console so maybe not an important distinction

Comment: I have made an update to give more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't pass a Role from another account.

"Passing" a Role is different than assuming one; this is why where is a separate "iam:PassRole" permission.  Passing a Role specifically refers to allowing *an AWS service* to assume that Role.  In order to prevent me from passing your Role to some service, which might allow me to read from or write to your account, AWS simply does not allow users to pass Roles belonging to other accounts.  You can only pass a Role belonging to your own account.

Unfortunately, Kinesis Data Streams don't support resource-based permission policies so you can't give permission for a Role in AccountB to access a Data Stream in AccountA anyway.  I think that your options are:

1. Keep everything in one account.
2. Use some other mechanism to transfer data from your Kinesis Data Stream into AccountB before ingesting it into Firehose.  One strategy that might work is to use the [Kinesis Client Library](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/field-notes-how-to-enable-cross-account-access-for-amazon-kinesis-data-streams-using-kinesis-client-library-2-x/).